# XPages bound to field expecting a number but document has text instead

Tags: xpages-ssjs

I have a repeat control bound to a view data source. A computed field within the repeat control is bound to a field which 'should' always be a double as I'm showing it as currency with a USD and $ and forced to 2dp.

My problem is some documents (from old Notes system) have text in them! and I now get an error  "Cannot format given Object as a Number". There must be something I can do to check and convert to a number first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [`xp:customConverter`](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/converters-on-an-xpage.htm) to remove any text and convert the value to number